# How to extract associative binary operations from a class of binary operations on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-equations, elementary-functions

I would like to find (all) **associative** binary operations of the form

$$u_{1}*u_{2}=\ln{\left[e^{u_{1}}+e^{u_{2}}\right]}+Q\left(u_{2}-u_{1}\right),$$ where $Q$ is an arbitrary function.

My effort:

beside the trivial $Q\equiv0$ that provides the associativity of $*$, function $$Q\left(u_{2}-u_{1}\right)=-\ln\left[e^{u_1}+e^{u_2} \right]-\ln\left[e^{-u_1}+e^{-u_2} \right]$$ can be written as 
$$Q\left(u_{2}-u_{1}\right)=-\ln\left[2+e^{-(u_2-u_1)}+e^{(u_2-u_1)}\right],$$ so that
$$u_{1}*u_{2}=u_1+u_2-\ln{\left[e^{u_{1}}+e^{u_{2}}\right]}$$ is an associative binary operation.

By random trial and error, I have checked many other functions $Q$ but failed to obtain associativity of $*$.  Is there a systematic way to determine what $Q$ provide for associativity of $*$?

Comment: You can set up the functional equation for what it means to be associative, but I imagine it's hard to extract all possible $Q$ from something like $\ln\left(\dfrac{e^a+e^{Q(c-b)}(e^b+e^c)}{e^c+e^{Q(b-a)}(e^a+e^b)}\right)=Q(c-\ln(e^a+e^b)-Q(b-a))-Q(-a+\ln(e^b+e^c)+Q(c-b))$

Comment: May Maple (or the like) hold any hope?